# Select box binding in blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor

I am trying to bind `CountryId` in the model to the value of a selected item of `SelectList` in Blazor. All of the Country items come in a list like `{CountryId, CountryName}` object. I do the code like so:

```
    <InputSelect @bind-Value="model.ByCountryId" class="form-control">
        @if (model?.Countries != null)
        {
           @foreach (var cnt in model.Countries)
           {
               <option value="@cnt.Id">@cnt.Name</option>
           }
        }
     </InputSelect>
```

And code block:

```
@code {

BrandModel model = new BrandModel();

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    model = new BrandModel
    {
        Id = 19,
        ByCountryId = 1,
        Countries = new List<ent.Country>
            {
                new ent.Country { Id = 1, Name = "Azerbaijan" },
                new ent.Country { Id = 2, Name = "Turkey" }
            },
        IsActive = true,
        Name = "Brand"
    };
}
```

But this execution gives me this error in the browser:

> blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM: System.MissingMethodException:
> Constructor on type 'System.ComponentModel.ByteConverter' not found.

What is the convenient way of binding `<select>` and `model.data` in Blazor?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It works well when I put the `<InputSelect>` in a `<EditForm Model="@model">..</EditForm >`and there's no problem in your data binding.

Try to use below code to set `<BlazorLinkOnBuild>false</BlazorLinkOnBuild>` in the csproj file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <BlazorLinkOnBuild>false</BlazorLinkOnBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Refer to https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7784

**Update:**

Use `<select>` tag instead of `<InputSelect>` like

```
<select @bind="model.ByCountryId">
        @if (model?.Countries != null)
        {
            @foreach (var cnt in model.Countries)
            {
                <option value="@cnt.Id">@cnt.Name</option>
            }
        }
</select>
```

Comment: I did as you said but get the same unhandled exception:(((. 
I think the problem is about binding byte type. Because error description is like that:

`WASM: System.InvalidOperationException: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputSelect 1[System.Byte] does not support the type 'System.Byte'`

Comment: @Emba Ayyub I do not see where you use the byte..What do your model of `Country` and `BrandModel` llook like? Since it works well when I set the Id for `int`

Comment: My model is like that
`public class BrandModel
    {
        public short Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public byte ByCountryId { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: @Emba Ayyub  I remove the error using `<select>` tag and above `<BlazorLinkOnBuild>false</BlazorLinkOnBuild>` in csproj file.See my update.

Comment: @Emba Ayyub Great.Could you [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you have resolved the problem

Comment: ```<BlazorLinkOnBuild>false</BlazorLinkOnBuild>``` removed from Blazor in latest version

Comment: I have API data for dropdown list and want to rebuild after call again to API but it seems that loop is not working second time. @Ryan do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 16):

This is an example on how one can display a list of countries in a select element, and retrieve the selected country code or ID.

```
<select class="form-control" @bind="@SelectedCountryID">

    <option value=""></option>
    @foreach(var country in CountryList)
    {
        <option value = "@country.Code"> @country.Name </option >
    }
}

</select>

<p>@SelectedCountryID</p>
```

##### Code block

```
@code {

    string selectedCountryID;

    string SelectedCountryID
    {
        get => selectedCountryID;
        set
        {
            selectedCountryID = value;

        }
    }

    List<Country> CountryList = new List<Country>() { new Country ("USA", "United States"),
                                                      new Country ("UK", "United Kingdom") };

    public class Country
    {

        public Country(string code, string name)
        {
            Code = code;
            Name = name;
        }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
}
```

---

This code is suitable to be integrated with other select elements to form cascading dropdown experience (a list of cities that is populated after selecting a country, etc.). Just copy the code snippet to your Index.razor file and execute it...

Comment: As I showed, I did it exactly the same but getting the error. I don't know why?

Comment: What do you mean by saying you did it exactly the same ? What does model stand for ? What does model.Countries stand for ? Please, show your entire code if you want me to point out what is wrong with it...

Comment: I edited my question and added all of the code there.

Comment: Your SelectedCountryID is "", where do you initially bind?

Answer (score 2):

`<InputSelect>` works for me In .NET 5. For every Inputs (text, number, date, select, checkbox etc) I use `<EditForm>` with `Model`.

```
<EditForm Model="item">
   <InputSelect @bind-Value="item.CountryId">
      <option value=""></option>
      @foreach (var c in countries)
      {
         <option value="@c.Id">@c.Name</option>
      }
   </InputSelect>
</EditForm>
```

For this example: `ItemModel item` has at least property `CountryId` and `List<CountryModel> countries` has at least properties `int Id` and `string Name`

Answer (score 0):

Working fine in Core 6 using API in blazor

```html
<InputSelect @bind-Value="patientCreateDTO.DoctorId" class="form-control" id="doctorid">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    @foreach(var doctor in doctorslist)
    {
        <option value="@doctor.Id">@doctor.Doctor_name</option>
    }
</InputSelect>
```

and here is the code

```csharp
private List<DoctorReadDTO> doctorslist = new();

// ...

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var response = await dService.GetDoctor();
    if (response.Success)
    {
        doctorslist = response.Data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-select" id="instant" @bind="_selected">
    <option value="Y">Y</option>
    <option value="N">N</option>
</select>
```

c#

```
@code {
    var _selected="Y";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`InputSelect` example with enum values and foreach option.

```
<InputSelect @bind-Value="context.Severity" class="form-control">
    @foreach (var severityEnum in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Severity)).Cast<Severity>().Where(x => x != Severity.None).ToList())
    {
        <option value="@severityEnum">@severityEnum.ToString()</option>
    }
</InputSelect>

public enum Severity
{
    None = 0,
    Critical = 1,
    High = 2,
    Medium = 3,
    Low = 4
}
```

I would recommend `InputSelect` over native html `select` if you need to receive and validate user input.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-and-input-components?view=aspnetcore-7.0#built-in-input-components