# Cascading Dropdown in Blazor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I'm using server side Blazor - I have my list of countries in the country table with two columns- CountryCode and CountryName. How do i dispaly the data using InputSelect to select a countryname and populate the countryCode
Here is my razor page:

```
<EditForm Model="@DisplayCountry" OnValidSubmit="@InsertCountry">
<DataAnnotationsValidator />
<ValidationSummary />

<div class="col-12 row">
    <label class="col-2 font-weight-bold">CountryCode:</label>
    <InputSelect id="CountryCode" @bind-Value="DisplayCountry.CountryCode" />
    &nbsp;<ValidationMessage For="@(() => DisplayCountry.CountryCode)" />
</div>

<div class="col-12 row">
    <label class="col-2 font-weight-bold">CountryName:</label>
    <InputText id="CountryName" @bind-Value="DisplayCountry.CountryName" placeholder="CountryName" />
    &nbsp;<ValidationMessage For="@(() => DisplayCountry.CountryName)" />
</div>


<br />
<div class="col-12 row">
    <span class="col-2"></span>
    <input type="submit" class="form-control col-1 btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using ViewBag, and ViewData in your controller?

Comment: Its unclear which part of the problem you need help with - have you managed to obtain the list from your database? If so untag SQL Server. Are you trying to pass the data to the client? Are you trying to display the data on the client? Are you trying to write some client side code? Please clarify so that someone can assist you.

Comment: I'm using server side Blazor - I have my list of countries in the country table with two columns- CountryCode and CountryName. How do i dispaly the data using InputSelect to select a countryname and populate the countryCode?

Comment: Please add any clarifications directly into the question. And remove the SQL Server tag as its not an SQL Server issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple demo like below:

*Model:*

```
namespace BlazorApp1.Models
{
    public class Country
    {
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*Razor:*

```
@page "/counter"
@using BlazorApp1.Models
@using BlazorApp1.Data
@inject CountryService countryService

    <EditForm Model="@DisplayCountry">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />

        <div class="col-12 row">
            <label class="col-2 font-weight-bold">CountryCode:</label>
            <InputSelect @bind-Value="@coutryName" class="form-control">
                    @foreach (var cnt in DisplayCountry)
                    {
                        <option value="@cnt.CountryName">@cnt.CountryCode</option>
                    }

            </InputSelect>
            &nbsp;<ValidationMessage For="@(() => DisplayCountry[0].CountryCode)" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 row">
            <label class="col-2 font-weight-bold">CountryName:</label>
            <InputText id="CountryName" @bind-Value="@coutryName" placeholder="CountryName" class="form-control"/>
            &nbsp;<ValidationMessage For="@(() => DisplayCountry[0].CountryName)" />
        </div>


        <br />
        <div class="col-12 row">
            <span class="col-2"></span>
            <input type="submit" class="form-control col-1 btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
        </div>
   </EditForm>
@code
{    
    string coutryName;
    List<Country> DisplayCountry = new List<Country>();
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        DisplayCountry = countryService.GetCountry();
    }
}
```

*Service:*

```
namespace BlazorApp1.Data
{
    public class CountryService
    {
        public List<Country> GetCountry()
        {
            //for easy testing,I just hard-coded assignment
            //you could get the data from database like
            //_context.Country.ToList()
            var data = new List<Country>()
            {
                new Country() { CountryCode="1011", CountryName="USA"},
                new Country() { CountryCode="1021", CountryName="Africa"},
                new Country() { CountryCode="1031", CountryName="China"},
                new Country() { CountryCode="1041", CountryName="UK"},

            };
            return  data;
        }
    }
}
```

*Startup.cs:*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    //register the service
    services.AddSingleton<CountryService>();
}
```

*Results:*
[image]

If you do not want to get data from service,you could seed data like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58485439/select-box-binding-in-blazor).

Comment: I implemented this but i was getting the following error message: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CountryModel>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<BlazorApp1.Models.CountryModel>' 
 and:  Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0117 'Country' does not contain a definition for 'CountryName' DataAccessLibrary C:\Projects\ITSMCourses\DataAccessLibrary\CountryData.cs 18 Active.

Comment: Are you sure your namespace is correct?There is no need to change your namespace as mine.

Comment: Also,it seems you have two project?Could you share more detailed code?

Comment: I was able to populate the data when it's hardcoded from the drop down menu but not from the database table.

Comment: Thanks Rena, Got it working now. It turns out that the @foreach variable was wrongly applied from my side.

Comment: please have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61384332/blazor-cascading-dropdown-menu-on-inputselect-not-loading