# Select box is blank after an option is selected

Tags: html, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an Html select box in my Blazor form where a user may select a grade from a `GradesTable`. However when the user picks an option, the select box rectangle goes into a blank state. I have tried to use a `selected` in the `<option>` tag but the box then locks onto the last option when a selection is made. Is there anyway to show the selected option in the box?

```
<label for="Grade">Choose a Grade:</label>
<select Name="Grade" id="Grade" @bind="selectedGrade">
    <option value="">---No Grade---</option>
    @foreach (var item in grade)
    {
        <option value="@item.Id" selected>@item.GradeDescription</option>
    }
</select>

@code{
   private int? selectedGrade;
    private List<GradeTable> FilteredGrades => selectedGrade.HasValue ?
    grades.Where(s => s.Grade==selectedGrade.Value).ToList() :
    grades;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, `selected` means that the option having this attribute is the one selected, here you are assigning it to every `<option>` in the `foreach`. Secondly, here a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58485439/select-box-binding-in-blazor). What is the type of `selectedGrade` ?

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine It is an int

Comment: I think the binding process, here, returns a string. Try defining `selectedGrade` as a string.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine I cannot use a string as my code block uses a `selectedGrade.Hasvalue`. I have updated the question, my apologies

Comment: Well you have several possibilities to fix this, here two: 1) Use `@onchange` and cast the string value as an `int`. 2) Create a new parameter and define `get` and `set` to get/assign `selectedGrade` as a string.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine consider me confused :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248200/discussion-between-kibofigs-and-t-trassoudaine).

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting the `selected` attribute correctly: `selected=@"selectedGrade == item.Id"`

`true` will render the attribute, and `false` will not.

Do this:

```
<label for="Grade">Choose a Grade:</label>
<select Name="Grade" id="Grade" @bind="selectedGrade">
    <option value="">---No Grade---</option>
    @foreach (var item in grade)
    {
        <option value="@item.Id" selected=@"selectedGrade == item.Id">@item.GradeDescription</option>
    }
</select>

@code {
    private int? selectedGrade;
}
```