# How can I get the index of a selcted item in a select input in Blazor

Tags: blazor

I have the following Blazor code:

```
<div>
<select @oninput="(e)=>{test=e.Value.ToString();}">
    <option value="105" selected>105</option>
    <option value="107">107</option>
</select>
</div>
<p>@test</p>
```

Here I retrieve the selected value.

But, how can I get the index of the selected option?

Thank you

Comment: Why would you want that? What would the index be for a member of an optgroup?

Comment: Store your objects in a c# list and bind a value with a unique ID of this object, You should be able to get anything you need from there. [Binding related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58485439/select-box-binding-in-blazor)

Comment: If the index is the value you want, then. . . build your options with the index as their value.  But this is not normal-- you should have a key in your data class.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select @oninput="(e)=>{test=e.Value.ToString();}">
   @foreach (var option in SelectListOptionValues.Select((val, idx) => new { Value = val, Index = idx })
   {
      <option @key="option" value="@option.Value">@option.Value (@option.Index)</option>
   }
</select>

@code {
  private List<int> SelectListOptionValues => new List<int> { 105, 107 };
}
```

You can now access the index via the option.Index property...

If you want to pass the index on the oninput event then:

```
(e)=>{test=e.Value.ToString(); index=SelectListOptionValues.IndexOf(e.Value);}
```